# Does milk tea cause darkening of the skin?

Tags: dermatology, milk, tea, hyperpigmentation

Will having *milk tea* more than three times in a day cause darkening of the skin.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a common misconception and there are many non-peer-reviewed articles online debunking this myth; like [this example](https://www.onlymyhealth.com/amp/grandma-myths-does-tea-make-skin-turn-darker-1300873048).

In a review of literature, [Tea and Health: Studies in Humans](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4055352/), Khan and Mukhtar report the evidence for various health effects of tea, and hyperpigmentation (darkening of the skin) is not among them.

I cannot find any evidence of tea or milk causing darkening of the skin.

In fact, extracts from some tea seem to have an effect on reducing melanin production *in vitro*. In this paper, [Anti-melanogenic effects of black, green, and white tea extracts on immortalized melanocytes](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4483495/), Camellia sinensis water extracts reduced melanin production. It is important to note that this is a laboratory study and I could not find any evidence that drinking tea has any effect on skin pigmentation.